# Converting a PDE to a matrix form

Tags: matrices, partial-differential-equations

I have to solve the problem
$U_{xx}-U_{xy}+2U_y+Uyy-3U_{yx}+4U=0$
using diagonal matrix as described in [this article](http://www1.maths.leeds.ac.uk/~kersale/Teach/M3414/Notes/m3414_1.pdf) **page 44 section 3.2**

But my problem is there the matrix A is symmetric matrix  assuming derivatives commute. But in the given problem coefficient of $U_{xy}=-1$ and coefficient of $U_{yx}=-3$.
Then the corresponding matrix
  A=$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1/2 & -1 \\
          \\
        -3 & 0  \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$
Then the matrix A is not symmetric

Comment: That depend on the hypotesis about the solutions, in general $U_{xy}=U_{yx}$. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_of_second_derivatives . If you assume that your matrix is symmetric. In your text says "Without
loss
of
generalit
y
w
e
can
tak
e
the
matrix
A
=
(
a
ij
)
;
i;
j=1 n;to be symmetric (assuming derivatives commute)"

Comment: Then if $U_{xy}=U_{yx}$ your problem is: $$U_{xx}-4U_{xy}+2U_y+U_{yy}+4U=0$$
And your matrix is:
$$A=
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & -2 \\
          \\
        -2 & 1  \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$
The first term is $1$ because in the sum appears once (same with $U_{yy}$) and the symetric are $-2$ because they appear twice  in the sum

Comment: I thought $a_{ij}$ are coefficient values of derivatives,I don;t understand how $U_{xy}$ coefficient is  -2. Shouldn't it be -4.On what basis is it divided by 2 and the coefficient is made as -2.Can you please explain it a little bit more

Comment: Also doesn't this method necessarily need the matrix to be symmetric.In that case definitely shouldn't it be $U_{xy}$=$U_{yx}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As posted in the commentaries depends on the hypothesis about the solutions. First I'm going to assume $U_{xy}=U_{yx}$.
On your article the derivatives of grade $2$ are writed as the next form:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}a_{ij}\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x_i\, \partial x_j} $$
What can be writed as:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{ii}+\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1,i\neq j}^{n}a_{ij}\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x_i\, \partial x_j} $$
Assuming that your derivatives commute:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{ii}+\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j<i}^{n}(a_{ij}+a_{ji})\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x_i\, \partial x_j} $$
Here is the keypoint exist more than one matrix $A$ that match with this pattern for example:
$$
  A=      \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & -1 \\
          \\
        -3 & 1  \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$ 
But if you assume that the matrix is symmetric:
$$
  A=      \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & -2 \\
          \\
        -2 & 1  \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$ 
What is the result of putting your equation in the next way:
$$U_{xx}-U_{xy}+2U_y+Uyy-U_{yx}-2U_{yx}+4U=0$$
$$U_{xx}-U_{xy}+2U_y+Uyy-U_{xy}-2U_{yx}+4U=0$$ 
$$U_{xx}-2U_{xy}+2U_y+Uyy-2U_{yx}+4U=0$$
Using the fact that $U_{xy}=U_{yx}$. The advantage of assuming $A$ symmetric allows you to use the diagonalization tool as you can see in rest of the article.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.So the method in article only works for symmetric matrices right?

Comment: First if the decomposition in $P^TAP=\Lambda$ with $P$ orthogonal and $\Lambda$ real could be possible to apply it to other matrices. Second if $U_{xy}=U_{yx}$ is alway possible to put $A$ in a symmetric form (taking the average of the coefficient of $U_{xy}$ and $U_{yx}$ in the position $a_{12}$ and $a_{21}$.